# Finding similar elements of an array as a value of a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Let's say I have the following hash:

```
hash = {"One" => [1,2,3,4], "Two" => [1,5,6,7], "Three" => [1,8,9,10]}
```

I want to create a conditional statement that puts a string if each first element of ever array is equal to 1.

Since each array in our hashes Key-pair values starts with 1, the conditional would be true.

This is some code I've been trying:

```
if hash.each_value {|array| array[0] == 1}
  puts "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if hash.all?{|_, array| array[0] == 1}
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

or

```
if hash.values.all?{|array| array[0] == 1}
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Comment: How would I go about writing it so it could test if the first, second, third or fourth elements were all the same? Could I use the same method but input a different block?

Comment: Is that what you really wanted to ask? Then you asked an XY-problem. Whether or not that is the case, **you should ask that in a new thread**.

Comment: I am simply curious for other scenarios I may face in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.values.all?{|e|e.first == 1} ? "Hello World" : nil
```